# Is there a way to know if a page request came from the same application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, request, referrer

In Rails3, is there a way to check if the page I'm rendering now was requested from the same application, without the use of the hardcoded domain name?

I currently have:

```
def back_link(car_id = '')
  # Check if search exists
  uri_obj = URI.parse(controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]) if controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].present?
  if uri_obj.present? && ["my_domain.com", "localhost"].include?(uri_obj.host) && uri_obj.query.present? && uri_obj.query.include?('search')
    link_to '&#x25C0; '.html_safe + t('back_to_search'), url_for(:back) + (car_id.present? ? '#' + car_id.to_s : ''), :class => 'button grey back'
  end
end
```

But this doesn't check for the "www." in front of the domain and all other possible situations.

It would also be nice if I could find out the specific controller and action that were used in the previous page (the referrer).

Comment: beware, all browsers don't send referer information

Comment: are there any specific ones that don't send the referer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way.

If you look around the web, find a site with a search feature, and follow the link you'll see a param showing what was searched for.

That's a good way to do it.

Doing it by `HTTP_REFERER` seems a bit fragile, and won't work, for example, from a bookmark, or posted link.

eg.

```
/cars/12?from_search=sports+cars
```

then you can just look up the `params[:from_search]`

If you really need to do it by `HTTP_REFERER` then you probably dont have to worry about subdomains. Just;

```
def http_referer_uri
  request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] && URI.parse(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])
end

def refered_from_our_site?
  if uri = http_referer_uri
    uri.host == request.host
  end
end

def refered_from_a_search?
  if refered_from_our_site?
    http_referer_uri.try(:query)['search']
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! really nice clean code there! especially like the && usage (but don't know exactly what it returns, nil or false if first condition isn't met?). Using params is more robust, so I think I'll go with that.

Comment: The point is, that I don't want it to work from a bookmark or posted link, because the purpose of it is to make a button to go back to the search (if a search was previous made). If not, then don't display the button.

Comment: @Cristian why don't you just let the user hit their back button then? Are you trying to engineer something you don't need?

Comment: I have a bit of a special situation: the search listing is not ordinary, it allows for each item to expand without requesting another page, so this method allows me to specify an ID as an anchor, that will make the item open up and scroll the page to it once you go back to the search. From a UX point of view, it may have its disadvantages and advantages, but I think it might be helpful, for at least some users.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
ref = URI.parse(controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])

if ref.host == ENV["HOSTNAME"]
  # do something
```

To try and get the controller/action from the referring page:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(url.path)
  #=> {:controller => "foo", :action => "bar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create an `internal_request?` method utilizing `request.referrer`.

Compare the `host` and `port` of the `request.referrer` with your Application's `host` and `port`.

```
require 'uri' # Might be necesseary.

def internal_request?
  return false if request.referrer.blank?

  referrer = URI.parse( request.referrer )

  application_host = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[ :host ]
  application_port = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[ :port ]

  return true if referrer.host == application_host && referrer.port == application_port

  false
end
```

And then call it like this where you need it, most likely in `application_controller.rb`:

```
if internal_request?
  do_something
end
```

Some caveats:

- This might need to be modified if you're using subdomains. Easy, though.
- This will require you to be setting your host and port for ActionMailer in your configuration, which is common.
- You might want to make it the reverse, like `external_request?` since you're likely handling those situations uniquely. This would allow you to do something like this:

  ```
  do_something_unique if external_request?
  ```